# (Fluent)NHibernate and PostgreSQL 9

Tags: c#, mysql, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate

We currently have a FNH - MySQL 5.1 DAL in our .Net LOB app. Some recent tests we did showed that PostgreSQL does perform faster than MySQL, and we believe the table partitioning feature in PostgreSQL will be very important with a table in our database we  foresee to grow into 100 million rows and more (in production).

Has anyone upgraded to PostgreSQL 9 and what recommendations do you have for migrating to PostgreSQL in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have 100 million rows yet, but when 9.0 came up, I upgraded all my c#-nhibernate-postgresql projects from 8 to 9. I don't see a reason to use the older version anyways. Currently 4 projects are happily running on 9 with no problems.

One tip (tho it's no brainer), http://www.enterprisedb.com/ gives support with enterprise caliber, and I recommend you to use their tuning software and other services if needed. (I'm not affiliated with the company in any ways)

Comment: Thanks detay. I was also thrown by "PostgreSQL82Dialect". I'll give it a go now.